# Hadoop Hue Failed to access filesystem root

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, configuration, cloudera, hue

I am taking this message from the Quick Start Wizard of Hue .

```
hadoop.hdfs_clusters.default.webhdfs_url    Current value: http://localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1
                                            Failed to access filesystem root
```

[image]

I tried this, [Hue: Failed to access filesystem root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35187085/hue-failed-to-access-filesystem-root) , but nothing changed. Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried again the  [configuration](http://gethue.com/how-to-configure-hue-in-your-hadoop-cluster/)  steps from the start and it worked....

Comment: @rahul I just tried again the configurations steps. Probably I had miss something the first time.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the *docker* version of Quickstart on macOS, the reason could be that `Docker Desktop` is not allocating enough memory.

A solution is to... add more.
On click on the Docker icon in the menu bar > "Preferences..." > "Advanced" tab

Then set the memory to (at least) 4GB.

Comment: Very helpful, all I had to do was to increase my memory size, i pushed it a notch up by 6GB and all of the errors went away. I am using the Cloudera docker version.